# Pull request to torvalds/linux

Tags: github, linux-kernel, pull-request

I have created a pull request in GitHub repo [torvalds/linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux). This repo contains source code of Linux kernel.

It shows this message to me:

[image: Screenshot of GitHub repo pull request]

Is my Pull Request successfully created or not? When I load the main page it shows me this:

[image: GitHub main repo screenshot]

In spite of clicking on "Compare & pull request" so many times it again shows same when I load the page.

Comment: Check for yourself: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pulls?q=is%3Apr+author%3AArnavNagpurkar+. Or read what it says: _"An owner of this repository has limited the ability to open a pull request to users that are collaborators on this repository."_. Is that you?

Answer (score 2):

Linus doesn't take PR on github:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/17#issuecomment-5654674

Instead, this is how you should submit your changes:
https://docs.kernel.org/process/submitting-patches.html